# IndexedDB addRecord with multiple JavaScript worker thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, indexeddb, web-worker, dexie

Suppose I have this series of Files

`20,21,22,23,24,...,35`

I separated that series into some packs by the below snippet code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _Thread_SerieLength; i++) {
    if (data_Seriepack.instanceList[index] !== undefined) {
        bachPack.push(data_Seriepack.instanceList[index]);
        index = index + threadSerieCount;
    }
}
```

So pack1 is `20,24,28,32`, p2=`21,25,29,33` , p3=`22,26,30,34` and p4=`23,27,31,35`

in the other side I have a `js` file named `BlobDownloader.js` as worker thread
BlobDownloader will download pack Urls and insert them into `indexedDb` so the code of worker thread is :

```
self.onmessage = function (event) {
    var dbObject = new ClientDataBase(event.data.dbName);
    if (event.data != undefined) {
        var Urls = event.data.pack;
        Urls.forEach(function (url, index, arr) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    blob;
            xhr.open("GET", url.imageId, false);
            xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    blob = xhr.response;
                    console.log("Befor added to DB:" + url.imageId);
                    dbObject.addRecord(url.imageId, url.imageIndex, event.data.serieUID, blob, blob.byteLength, "").then(function (e) {
                        console.log("After added to DB:" + e);
                        postMessage(e);
                        if (index == arr.length - 1) {
                            self.close();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }, false);
            xhr.send();
        });
    }
}
```

and calling that worker is :

```
    for (var j = 0; j < self.maxThreadNumber; j++) {
        bachPack = [];
......
        self.customThreadDownloader[j] = new Worker('../Scripts/Metric/Downloader/BlobDownloader.js');
        var content = {
            pack: bachPack,
            dbName: dataBaseObject[self.Study.studyIndex].dbName,
            dbVersion: dataBaseObject[self.Study.studyIndex].dbVersion,
            serieUID: self.Tbox.id,
            threadIndex: j
        }
        self.customThreadDownloader[j].postMessage(content);
        self.customThreadDownloader[j].onmessage = function (evt) {
            counterpack++;
            var dataIndex = self.Urls.indexOf(evt.data);
            console.log("> Added To DB: " + dataIndex);
        }
....
    }
```

so 4 threads will run parallel by that `for` loop 
so the output in my expect would be:

`21,22,23,24,25,26,27...35`

but it is something different like:

`21,25,29,33,23,27,31,35,22,26,30,34,...` = (p2,p4,p3,p1)

or

`20,24,28,32,22,26,30,34,21,25,29,33,23,27,31,35`=(p1,p3,p2,p4)

which mean one thread run until it finished and then another be run to end, it seems there is no parallel running when I am using IndexedDB.

so when I remove this:

```
dbObject.addRecord(url.imageId, url.imageIndex, event.data.serieUID, blob, blob.byteLength, "").then(function (e) {
    console.log("After added to DB:" + e);
    //  postMessage(e);
    if (index == arr.length - 1) {
        self.close();
    }
});
```

or calling `postMessage(e);` after `dbObject.addRecord` everything will works fine.

So is there a problem with using IndexedDb in Worker Thread?

Or is there a way to do this scenario ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"the output in my expect would be"_ `21,22,23,24,25,26,27...35` - this output will happen if the code runs synchronously and each pack is processed one after another, maybe you misunderstood **parallel processing** s. This `(p2,p4,p3,p1)` or that `(p1,p3,p2,p4)` is an expected output of parallel processing. The way you want packs to be processed is something like a **queue**, you will need to implement **worker queue**. Also something else I see you send empty array of urls to your worker always `bachPack = [];`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I understand parallel processing as well, when I removed `addRecord` output will be something like I want with a little different which is acceptable, but by `addRecord` for ex `p1` will end and next `p4`, I don't want enforce thread to be run in order.